# How do we remove padding from CSS file by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have library file where padding is defined for common column class.

```
[class*="col_"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 0.5rem 1rem;
  max-width: 100%; }
```

I don't want to remove it, in fact I want to override CSS where I want to remove padding style itself calling either by JavaScript or jQuery.

```
[class*="col_"] {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 max-width: 100%; }
```

Comment: add padding 0 to it in your override class CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all elements that match that selector

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("[class*=col_]");
elements.forEach(e => { 
     e.style.padding = '';
}
```

Or add a new style rule on the fly:

```
let newStyle = document.createElement('style');
newStyle.id = Date.now(); //set a id for removing the style later if necessary
newStyle.innerHTML = `
    [class*="col_"] {
       box-sizing: border-box;
       max-width: 100%; 
    }`;

document.body.appendChild(newStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to set the padding explicitly on the elements:

```
$("[class*=col_]").css("padding", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class like:
`.no_padding {padding:0;}`

And then, you can add that class to the specific elements you want using javascript or jquery:

```
// js
var element = document.getElementById("specific_element");
  element.classList.add("no_padding");

// jquery
$("#specific_element.col_x").addClass("no_padding");
```